# Inbound TCP/IP connection failed

Tags: ros, wifi, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting this warning when launching a .launch file. I have already configured my network and i have also exported master URI on slave.

```
Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: connection from sender terminated before handshake header received. 0 >bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details
```

Why is this happening? I'm using ros on two pc's connected via wifi. Pinging each one i get approx 20ms of delay.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240364/inbound-tcp/ip-connection-failed/) by [Oper](https://answers.ros.org/users/27436/oper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also had this problem. I solved it with putting off the Anti Virus software and the firewall

---

Originally posted by [anonymous27503](https://answers.ros.org/users/27503/anonymous27503/) with karma: 36 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also have this problem.  Running Ubuntu 16.04 and Kinetic.

Just running:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('connection_failed_debug', anonymous=True)
    rospy.spin()
```

will give me the message:

```
[WARN] [WallTime: 1473173287.273779] Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: connection from sender terminated before handshake header received. 0 bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1473173295.881939] Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: connection from sender terminated before handshake header received. 0 bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details.
```

This is probably only on a loaded machine...

---

Originally posted by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) with karma: 140 on 2016-09-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also have this problem. I am on a Ubuntu 14.04 using ROS Indigo. I am working with actionlib and everytime I launch a test client to check the server actions, at the end of the execution the message is shown.

```
Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: connection from sender terminated before handshake header received.
```

Any solution?

---

Originally posted by [raul.perula](https://answers.ros.org/users/1826/raul.perula/) with karma: 71 on 2017-01-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-03-07**:
Same problem..